# Trying to display a command link in an apexPage Message

Tags: visualforce

I have a simple controller method to set an apexpages.message. I want the message to contain a command link that will execute a controller method.

```
private void setPageMessage(){

    String  message = 'You are not a Team Member <apex:commandLink action="{!addToTeam}" value="click here" id="addToTeam" rendered="true"/> to add yourself to the team';
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Warning, message));
}
```

Page is pretty simple:

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="false" standardController="CustomObject__c" extensions="controllerExt">
  <apex:form>
    <apex:pageMessages escape="false"/>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

The message displays as "You are not a team member to add yourself to the team"

Is there a way to display the command link in the page message?

Comment: You could look into dynamic apex, but I'm not sure if that will get you want you want.

Comment: If the link should invoke a new instance of the controller, then you could use URLFOR

Comment: as @KeithC points out, URLFOR could only be used if using `apex:pageMessage` where the `summary` is constructed by merge fields and constants known to the VF page. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `escape="false"` you can include HTML in the message such as:

```
You are not a Team Member <a href="...">click here</a> to add yourself to the team
```

However, this only allows a HTTP GET to be done so it will be a navigation to a new page or a new instance of the current page rather than an action using the current controller and view state. You can include parameters including a return URL to eventually get back to the page that presented the message. So the `...` could be e.g.:

```
/apex/AddPage?id=123456789012345&retURL=%2Fapex%2FCurrentPage%3Fid%3D123456789012345
```

As the URL string is being built in Apex you can't use Visualforce functions to build it.

Comment: I think this is my only way.  I'll have to create a vf page that doesn't display anything and uses it's action method to create the team member.